# No Element found for Foo2 etc

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

http://www.gordonlundie.com/Howe/#

Im trying to sort my carousel towards the base of the page, and it is saying no element found.

Can anyone advise on this error? I believe that all the js is loaded correctly.

thankyou in advance

The error above is fixed, however it appears to still be jumping to the top of the page and not scrolling through the elements

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `carouFredSel` on an element that doesn't exist.

As an example, you have this code:

```
$('#foo0').carouFredSel();
```

Without any element on the page with an id of `foo0`.  You need to specify valid id's for your jQuery selector.

Comment: sorry im lost as to what this means (im very new to jquery)

Comment: oh! ok, well i just loaded the whole js in the footer! is it because the script is after it perhaps?

Comment: The location of your script is fine.  The problem is that you don't have anything on the page with an id of `foo0`.  Just like there's nothing on the page with an id of `foo1`.  *However*, you do have an element with an id of `foo3`; you'll notice you don't have any errors for that.

Comment: ah i think its because im trying to load the rest i think, i remove them, see if it sorts the error

Comment: ok i removed them all bar the foo 3 (the one i want) and it still not working :S

Comment: What does "still not working" mean? You no longer have script errors like you did before.

Comment: yea but its still not scrolling through them, its still doing a jump to top on link click :S

Comment: it should scroll them which suggests to me its conflicting with something and im unsure where :S

Comment: That's a different problem than what this question was about; you should read up on the documentation from the library you're using to make sure you have the right HTML structure needed for the plugin.

Comment: HI @ek9nomik, i think i have explained the question clearly enough. I explained that it was saying no element found. I will however update my question to be more in line with what is required. As i have done as it asked and it appears to be still not working. I have copied the structure from the actual demo